# Is passenger name record (PNR)="codigo de reserva"?

Tags: traducción

The airline sent me an email with "confirmacion de compra", which has a "codigo de reserva", which I guess, (but that's what I'm asking) corresponds EXACTLY to the "passenger name record (PNR)". This is a international standard code for flights.

[I found this BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-38518799), with "codigo de reserva" in the title and says it's PNR. So, are they the same?

Comment: I never heard of PNR, but I do know that when I make an airline reservation, I'm given a reservation code, and "código de reserva" seems to correspond to that.

Answer (score 1):

El propio artículo que enlazas indica que así es como se llama comúnmente al (código del) PNR, aunque no sea esa la traducción literal:

> **Los especialistas lo llaman PNR** -acrónimo en inglés de Passenger Name Record (**en español, registro de nombre de pasajero**)- y almacena mucho más que los datos de tu vuelo.

Que "código de reserva" o "referencia de reserva" es al menos una de las maneras de referirse en español al código del PNR, parece confirmarse al observar las páginas de diferentes aerolíneas y agencias de viaje:

- Fly Emirates: [referencia de reserva](https://www.emirates.com/pe/spanish/help/faq/198348/where-can-i-find-the-booking-reference-pnr)
- Iberia: [código de reserva](https://www.iberia.com/web/product.do?cntCat=Productos/IBCOSEPOPUP&cntId=codigoreserva&modal=true&isPopup=true)
- Aerolíneas Argentinas: [código de reserva](https://www.aerolineas.com.ar/es-ar/reservas_servicios/chequea_tu_reserva)
- Lufthansa: [código de reserva](https://www.lufthansa.com/de/es/mis-reservas)

Otra forma también común sería [localizador](https://www.microsiervos.com/archivo/aerotrastorno/sabias-que-es-el-pnr.html) (tal como se ve en el enlace y en la propia página de Iberia), uso que viene recogido (aunque en un sentido algo amplio) en el [diccionario](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NXlCVDs).

Comment: We do use locator in English but according to WIkipedia it is not exactly the same as PNR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_locator